# How to fill drop down list values using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Provide simple code that can be used to fill HTML drop down list values dynamically using AngularJS code. Please include multiple solutions if possible.

Comment: Please see my answer to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of possible solutions.

HTML / AngularJS Code:

```
<div ng-controller="TheController" ng-app>

Location:     
<select ng-model="locationId" ng-options="item.LocationId as item.LocationName for item in locations"></select>
    <br/>         
    LocationId: {{locationId}} <br/>    
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function TheController($scope) {

    $scope.locations = [
        {LocationId : 1, LocationName : 'USA' },       
        {LocationId : 2, LocationName : 'Canada' },
        {LocationId : 3, LocationName : 'Pakistan' } ];

}
```

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8een5/1/

Comment: I'm so confused why you're using Stackoverflow

Comment: I am writing these questions for people who have no idea about AngularJS like myself. Can you please contribute via answers if possible?

Comment: Google has thousands of links and resources on ng-options.. SOF is for specific programming Q& A.